# In Chrome version 56 developer tools missing "Computed" tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have "Styles", "Event Listeners", "Dom Breakpoints" and "Properties" in the right mid pane.

I'm missing "Computed" there, as it was before:
http://docs.joomlabamboo.com/getting-started/how-to-use-the-computed-panel-in-the-chrome-inspector

What could be underlying reason and how to fix it?

Comment: Depending on the devtools frame width, "Computed" may be already displayed in a docked panel: https://puu.sh/wNHwl/b2b8c09d8e.png

Comment: Weird. Now I resized devtools frame to take more width and Computed pane reappeared. And after resize to less width, it still remains.

Answer (score 7):

it is about the space.

when the dev panel is large enough, the styles and computed can be shown in
the same space;hence, "Computed" disppear in the tabs.

[dev panel large enough to show both styles and computed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHzpS.png)

[dev panel too small to contain both styles and computed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6eNd.png).png

Answer (score 1):

Try it with fullscreen, it is shown then.